# Linux command to display the number of hard drive slots your machine has

Tags: linux, command-line

I'm currently working on a Linux machine and I want to know if there is a command that tells you the number of hard drive slots the actual machine has regardless of whether there are hard drives installed or not. I know reading the machine's manual provides that information but is there any way to get this information by command line?

I've tried lshw and dmidecode commands but they do not provide information on slots. This specific machine has 6 slots for hard drives to be installed with only 3 currently occupied. It does not have hardware raid either so I cannot use megacli.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take some time to read the help pages, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Your question does not seem to be about programming. Your question could be more appropriate on one of the many stackexchange sites, namely https://superuser.com/

Comment: Can’t you use fdisk?

Comment: It provides information on installed drives not the actual number of slots the machine has. There are commands where it will provide the slot number associated with the installed hard drive but I want to know if there is a command that can provide information on how many drive slots there are in the machine regardless of if there are hard drives installed or not. In my case, when there are not drives installed.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

What about this command:

```
smartctl --scan
```

Output:

```
/dev/sda -d scsi # /dev/sda, SCSI device
/dev/sdb -d scsi # /dev/sdb, SCSI device
/dev/sdc -d scsi # /dev/sdc, SCSI device
/dev/sdd -d scsi # /dev/sdd, SCSI device
/dev/sde -d scsi # /dev/sde, SCSI device
/dev/sdf -d scsi # /dev/sdf, SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,8 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_08], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,9 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_09], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,10 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_10], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,11 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_11], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,12 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_12], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,13 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_13], SCSI device
```

Comment: Are you sure this is ALL regardless of use? For example I see *only* /dev/sda and /dev/nvme0 and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

[`lsblk`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsblk.8.html) should list all block devices. If you want only physical disks you can use `lsblk -d`.

Example:

```
lsblk -o name,serial
```

Output:

```
NAME    SERIAL
sda     S2U5J1VZ500792                                       
├─sda1                  
└─sda9                  
sdb     W3APDFP8
├─sdb1                  
└─sdb9
```

Comment: Already tried that as well. It only shows installed drives. I'm looking for a command that tells you the number of hard drive slots the actual machine has regardless of whether there are hard drives installed or not.

Answer (score -1):

Can it be done by lspci or lsscsi command. It can tell you the PCI or SCSI slots available and used.